# Is it possible to use text-overflow in a div with fixed height but variable width?

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to find a solution to this problem. I made a div with a fixed height set on 30vw (the number doesn't really matter, but the fact that the height will change when you resize your browser horizontally does) and the width set on 100%, to make it responsive. I'm trying to find a way to use the options text-overflow: ellipsis in this situation, where the amount of lines that fit in the div change when you resize your browser. Do you guys have any clue how to handle this?

Html:

```
<div class="items">
            <img src="example.jpg">
            <div>
                <h3>Titel</h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin pulvinar, nisi sit amet commodo venenatis, est quam gravida magna, a varius orci nibh sed odio. Duis sollicitudin nibh lorem, id pellentesque mauris varius eu. Mauris porta elit a dui molestie, aliquet maximus neque hendrerit. Praesent neque sem, feugiat vel bibendum nec, mollis nec arcu. Aenean tristique urna at luctus tempus. Phasellus placerat, massa id maximus sodales, tellus ante luctus mi, sed faucibus odio nisi dictum nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce lobortis bibendum porta.Phasellus eu nisi viverra, dignissim ex vel, tempus mauris. Donec faucibus nibh urna, quis molestie turpis posuere vitae. Nullam eu semper ligula. Cras eu erat a elit commodo scelerisque eu non augue. Sed et interdum sem. Morbi tincidunt magna ac ante eleifend fermentum. Integer nunc dui, euismod vel tempor bibendum, scelerisque nec lacus. Aenean finibus eros ex, et aliquam sapien viverra eu. Integer posuere at dolor id semper. Cras quis lacinia neque. Curabitur lobortis erat sed est lobortis, sed tincidunt libero placerat. Maecenas lobortis non felis in ultricies.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Css

```
.items {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
margin: 15px 0;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
height: 17vw;
width: 100%;
}

.items img {
height: 100%;
}

.items p {
margin: 0px 40px 10px 40px;
text-overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Your height was set to 17% of the view WIDTH so you always had height reletive to width as the user screen changed. I changed the parent to `overflow: hidden;` and i think i might have got it how you want it. let me know if this helps. cheers

```
<div class="items">
    <img src="example.jpg">
    <div>
        <h3>Titel</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin pulvinar, nisi sit amet commodo venenatis, est quam gravida magna, a varius orci nibh sed odio. Duis sollicitudin nibh lorem, id pellentesque mauris varius eu. Mauris porta elit a dui molestie, aliquet maximus neque hendrerit. Praesent neque sem, feugiat vel bibendum nec, mollis nec arcu. Aenean tristique urna at luctus tempus. Phasellus placerat, massa id maximus sodales, tellus ante luctus mi, sed faucibus odio nisi dictum nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce lobortis bibendum porta.Phasellus eu nisi viverra, dignissim ex vel, tempus mauris. Donec faucibus nibh urna, quis molestie turpis posuere vitae. Nullam eu semper ligula. Cras eu erat a elit commodo scelerisque eu non augue. Sed et interdum sem. Morbi tincidunt magna ac ante eleifend fermentum. Integer nunc dui, euismod vel tempor bibendum, scelerisque nec lacus. Aenean finibus eros ex, et aliquam sapien viverra eu. Integer posuere at dolor id semper. Cras quis lacinia neque. Curabitur lobortis erat sed est lobortis, sed tincidunt libero placerat. Maecenas lobortis non felis in ultricies.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.items {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
margin: 15px 0;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
height: 30vh;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

.items img {
height: 100%;
}

.items p {
margin: 0px 40px 10px 40px;
text-overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Comment: It does hide the text that overflows, but it now cuts it off at the middle of the letters, but it's better than before so thanks!